# How do I call a function(with javascript) after getting a response from nodeJs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

```
        const response = await fetch('/sign-up', options);
        const responseJson = await response.json().then(function(){


        })
            const status = responseJson.status;

            if(status == 'created'){
                alert('Account has successfully created')
            }else if(status == 'exist'){
                if(responseJson.Username){
                    $("#Username").css('box-shadow', 'inset 0 0 0 1px #DE071C');
                    $("#Username").css('background-color', '#EEEFF1');
                    $("#Username_error").css('display', 'block');
                    document.getElementById('text_Username_error').innerHTML = "This ID already exists. Please choose a different ID"
                }

                if(responseJson.Email){
                    $("#Email").css('box-shadow', 'inset 0 0 0 1px #DE071C');
                    $("#Email").css('background-color', '#EEEFF1');
                    $("#Email_error").css('display', 'block');
                    document.getElementById('text_Email_error').innerHTML = "This email already exists. Please choose a different email"

                }
            }else if(status == 'error'){
                $("#error").css('display', 'block');
            }
```

I'm sending a request with 'post' method by using a fetch(), and the server will response by sending a json file to the client. I've checked the json file with `console.log(responseJson)` and it works just fine. Client receives the json file perfectly, but the if statement after receiving doesn't work. 
`responseJson.Username` or `responseJson.Email` is not the problem, because console.log shows the output perfectly. I think if statement ends before receiving data, but I can't figure out how to solve this. poor me....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You're already calling a function after getting a response, the callback to .then, it's just that the function is completely empty, so you're awaiting for undefined.

Comment: check the status.

Answer (score 1):

i think that if you use the await keyword, you don't need to append the .then function.
Try something like this

```
const responseJson = await response.json()
//call your function here
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically there are 2 ways to go about this issue, however, I would like to point out that you *should not* mix `async await` syntax with callback.

My suggested method based on your current code:

```
let response = await fetch('/sign-up', options);
response = await response.json();
if (response.status === 'created') {
  ...
} else if (response.status === 'exist') {
  ...
  if (response.Username) {
    ..
  }
}
...
```

I greatly encourage looking into object de-structuring as well if you have the time, as it will reduce the repetition of a certain attribute, in which the syntax can be changed to:

```
const response = await fetch('/sign-up', options);
const { status, Username, Email } = await response.json();
if (status === 'created') {
  ...
} else if (status === 'exist') {
  ...
  if (Username) {
    ..
  }
}
...
```